# Parsing JSON object using jQuery and GSON returned by Spring controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, gson

I was looking for some solution around here and I didnt find any correct answer to my question so I would like to ask you.

I have POJO with some simple attribs. and one List of another POJOs.

```
public class Standard implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private Set<Interpretation> interpretations = new LinkedHashSet<Interpretation>();
}

public class Interpretation implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
}
```

In my controller class, I am returning Standard POJO with GSON.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fillStandard", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getStandard(@RequestParam String id) {
    Standard s = DAOFactory.getInstance().getStandardDAO().findById(id);
    return new Gson().toJson(s);
}
```

The question is, am I able to get the list of interpretations in my Standard POJO using jQuery ? Something like :

```
function newStandard() {
$.get("standard/fillStandard.htm", {id:"fe86742b2024"}, function(data) {
    alert(data.interpretations[0].title);
});
```

}

Thanks a lot !

**EDIT:**
Well, thanks to @Atticus, there is solution of my problem. Hope that it will help somebody.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fillStandard", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Standard getStandard(@RequestParam String id) {
        Standard s = DAOFactory.getInstance().getStandardDAO().findById(id);
        return s;
    }
```

Using `@ResponseBody` allows you to return the whole POJO, but you need to add `produces="application/json"` to your `@RequestMapping` annotation. Then you will be able to catch a returning object as JSON in jQuery like as I supposed.

```
function newStandard() {
$.get("standard/fillStandard.htm", {id:"idOfStandard"}, function(data) {
    alert(data.id);    //Standard id
    alert(data.interpretations[0].title);   //id of Interpretation on first place in array
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have to create and register your custom serializer.

It goes like this:

```
//You create your builder that registers your custom serializer with the class you want to serialize
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Standard.class, new StandardSerializer());

//Then you create your Gson object
Gson gson = builder.create();
//Then you pass your object to the gson like
Standard s = DAOFactory.getInstance().getStandardDAO().findById(id);
gson.toJson(s);
```

Your serializer looks like this:

```
public class StandardSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Standard>{

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Standard src, Type typeOfSrc,
            JsonSerializationContext context) {

            JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
            //You put your simple objects in like this
            obj.add("id",new JsonPrimitive(src.getId()));
            //You put your complex objects in like this
            JsonObject interpretations = new JsonObject();
            //Here you need to parse your LinkedHashSet object and set up the values. 
            //For the sake of simplicity I just access the properties (even though I know this would not compile)
            interpretations.add("title", src.getInterpretation().getTitle());
            obj.add("interpretations", interpretations);
            return obj;
        }

}
```

In this case your Json would look something like:

```
{"id":"idValue", "title":"titleValue", "description":"descriptionValue", "interpretations":["id":"interpretationIdValue"]}
```

Now, you can access your data with `jQuery` like this:

```
function newStandard() {
$.get("standard/fillStandard.htm", {id:"fe86742b2024"}, function(data) {
    alert(data.interpretations.title);
});
}
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:**
I see that your response gets converted to the declared method argument type which is `String` (as stated [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html): 16.3.3.2 Supported method return types). But what you really want is your `Standrad` POJO converted to JSON. I am not very familiar with Spring but as I have read [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) (16.3.2.6 Producible Media Types) there is another, maybe easier solution. If you want to return a JSON object, then change the return type of the 
`getStandard` method to `Standard` instead of `String` and add `produces="application/json"` to your `@RequestMapping` annotation. As far as I have read this should tell `Spring` that the return type should be converted to JSON. In this case you do not need to use `Gson`.

Comment: I have edited my answer to contan the jQuery code too. You have to create a JSON object that contains the data you requested for. Well, this is how you send your data (on server side) to be able to receive what you need on client side.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I used your code and now in jQuery alert(data.toString) returns {"handler":{"interfaces":[{}],"constructed":true,"persistentClass":{},"overridesEquals":true,"entityName":"com.web.model.Standard","id":"fe86742b2024","target":{"id":"fe86742b2024","title":"fe86742b2024","description":"desc","interpretations":{"id":"5f5c9dc31119","title":"5.2.4","description":"desc"}},"initialized":true},"others":false,"interpretations":[],"comments":[]} and i cannot get anything from this. Neither data.id nor data.interpretations.id ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: For some reason your data is put into the target field of the JSON answer and other properties are also serialized. I can not say what the problem is without taking a look at the code. Could you send it to me (use the email address on my profile page)?

Comment: No problem. Just click on my name after this comment or under my answer and there it you will see my profile :)

Comment: YES, it works like a charm ! I was trying to return whole POJO Standard using `@ResponseBody` (btw. great Spring tool), but without `produces="application/json"` in `@RequestMapping` nothing has been sent back to my .get jQuery method. Therefor I started experimenting with returning String or HashMap (because this types are supported by default). Now I dont need neither GSON nor anything else. Thanks God and YOU too :D